# How to tell the target JSP to use in Jodd?

Tags: tomcat, jodd

Looking at the tutorial on http://joddframework.org/, one thing I cant figure out is how the target JSP is choosen. Would you help? Thank you.

Comment: Heya, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just head to [official docs](http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/results.html#dispatcher-result-dispatch) - again, it is just a convention, that goes like this.

If you have an action:

```
@MadvocAction
public class HelloAction {

    @Action
    public String world() {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

This action is mapped to action path: `/hello.world.html`. Result value is `ok`. The following list of JSPs are checked, in given order:

- /hello.world.html.ok.jspf
- /hello.world.html.ok.jsp
- /hello.world.html.jspf
- /hello.world.html.jsp
- /hello.world.ok.jspf
- /hello.world.ok.jsp
- /hello.world.jspf
- /hello.world.jsp
- /hello.ok.jspf
- /hello.ok.jsp
- /hello.jspf
- /hello.jsp
- /ok.jspf
- /ok.jsp

Dispatcher finds the first matching JSP(F). If no page is found, error 404 is returned. Dispatcher caches results, so scanning for each result value is done only once!

Please note this is default behavior, and its quite easy to add your own `Result` renderer and way how JSP are found.

Comment: Thak you very much. Helpfull answer

Comment: Great @MihaminaRakotomandimby, just mark it as an answer, please; so others can benefit as well. Thank you!